# Cannot run my jar, no error are returned (works from Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am new to Java, I just finished my first little project, and I would like to compile it into a JAR file. I did it from Eclipse with the Export method, I have selected my class containing the Main method, but when my JAR file is created, when I double click on it, the program just don't run. Nothing happen, I get no error.
Here is my Manifest file, auto-generated via Eclipse:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Did you try runnung the JAR from a command line using `java -jar yourfilename.jar`? Double-clicking might run a JAR file, or do something entirely different like extracting it with a ZIP archiver depending on system settings.

Comment: What is there in your jar file? AFAIK you need to run jar file from cmd using java -jar filename

Comment: Is this a command line application or a GUI?

Comment: With java -jar filename, it returns a NoClassDefFoundError and a ClassNotFoundException... Why do I get that? Everything isn't supposed to be into the JAR file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have external JAR dependencies that resolve just fine in Eclipse, but fail when you run the JAR from the command line. There are a couple of solutions for problems like this:

1. Add the path to each dependent JAR in your system classpath. This is
   the least desirable and least portable method.
2. Specify the path to each dependent JAR as a setting in your Manifest
   file. This is only a hair more portable than method 1), but can work
   well if you bundle your applications JAR file into a ZIP, along with
   all the dependent JAR's.
3. Bust open the dependent JAR's, extracting the classes and including
   them in your JAR. This is a very ugly solution but has been used by
   many open source projects in the early days of Java.
4. Use a solution like [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) to create a truly executable JAR
   with all dependencies accounted for. Somewhat proprietary but
   probably your best bet.

Good luck!

Comment: I am going to take a look at all these solutions, thanks a lot for helping ! Hope I will find something working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can you main method by right clicking in the java file editor and selecting "Run as", or from Menu/toolbar. 
When you double-click jar file outside of Eclipse it depends on your OS setting, which program will open the jar. Try to right-click on the jar and select "open with..." (or similar option) and select (or browse to) java executable.

Comment: Try to put some logging at the start of main method and run it from Eclipse, then check Console panel it eclipse for output.